# Proof of empirical temperature from Zeroth Law given in Kardar's book

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, temperature, calculus, equilibrium

I am studying Mehran Kardar's Statistical Physics of Particles. In chapter-1, they derive the existence of empirical temperature using Zeroth Law.
It is given as

> **Definition-** If two systems, A and B, are separately in equilibrium with a third system, C,
> then they are also in equilibrium with one another.
> Let the equilibrium state of systems $A,\;B,\;and\;C$ be described by the
> coordinates ${\{A1,A2,···,A_n}\},\;{\{B1,B2,··· ,B_n}\},\;and\;{\{C1,C2,··· ,C_n}\}$, respectively. The
> assumption that $A$ and $C$ are in equilibrium implies a constraint between
> the coordinates of A and C, that is, a change in $A_1$ must be accompanied by
> some changes in ${\{A2,··· ,C1,C2,···,C_n}\}$ to maintain equilibrium of A and C.
> So due to equilibrium of $A$ and $C$,
> $f_{AC}(A_1,...,A_n,C_1,...,C_n)=0\tag{1}$
> and due to equilibrium of $B$ and $C$,
> $f_{BC}(B_1,...,B_n,C_1,...,C_n)=0\tag{2}$
> This is equivalent to solving each of the above equations for C1 to yield
> $C_1=F_{AC}(A_1,...,A_n,C_2,...,C_n)\tag{3}$
> $C_1=F_{BC}(B_1,...,B_n,C_2,...,C_n)\tag{4}$
> Thus if C is separately in equilibrium with A and B, we must have
> $F_{AC}(A_1,...,A_n,C_2,...,C_n)=F_{BC}(B_1,...,B_n,C_2,...,C_n)\tag{5}$
> However, according to the zeroth law there is also equilibrium between
> A and B, implying the constraint
> $f_{AB}(A_1,...,A_n,B_1,...,B_n)=0\tag{6}$
> We can select any set of parameters ${\{A,B}\}$ that satisfy the above equation, and
> substitute them in $Eq. 5$. The resulting equality must hold quite independently of any set of variables ${\{C}\}$ in this equation. We can then change these
> parameters, moving along the manifold constrained by $Eq.6$, and $Eq.5$
> will remain valid irrespective of the state of $C$. Therefore, it must be possible
> to simplify $Eq.5$ by canceling the coordinates of $C$. Alternatively, we can
> select any fixed set of parameters $C$, and ignore them henceforth, reducing the
> condition $Eq.6$ for equilibrium of $A$ and $B$ to
> $\Phi_A(A_1,...,A_n)=\Phi_B(B_1,...,B_n)$

I am not able to understand the last paragraph of the proof.
How the equality in $Eq.5$ holds irrespective of $C's$. The line **"We can then change these parameters, moving along the manifold constrained by Eq.6, and Eq.5 will remain valid irrespective of the state of C. Therefore, it must be possible to simplify Eq.5 by canceling the coordinates of C"**, is not clear to me.

In all books, like Adkins' Equilibrium Thermodynamics, similar argument that $Eq.5$ holds irrespective of $C's$, so there is a function $\Phi$, is used.

But I am not able to understand this mathematically, what is going on in this argument.
Please help me in understamding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the argument is a bit difficult to penetrate. I will try to reformulate it here.

We consider all three systems at equilibrium with each other, i.e. $A\sim B$, $A\sim C$ and $B\sim C$. Since $A\sim B$, any equilibrium state of $C$ in the $AC$ system ($C\sim A$), must also be an equilibrium state of $C$ in the $BC$ system due to the transitivity of equilibrium. This is equivalent to saying, that if $A\sim B$ and $C\sim A$, then, for any fixed $(C_2, C_3,..., C_n)$, equations (1) and (2) must hold for the same $C_1$, because if they didn't, you would have $A\sim B$ and $A\sim (C_1,...,C_N)$ but $B\nsim (C_1,...,C_N)$, which would break the transitivity. The last statement is equivalent to equating the right parts of equations (3) and (4), leading to equation (5).

Putting it all together, we get that if $A\sim B$, then for any choice $(C_2, C_3,..., C_n)$ equation (5) must hold.

I hope it is more clear this way.

Comment: I have read your answer several times. Most of my doubts have been clarified. I have one doubt. We conclude that for any values ${\{C_2,C_3,..,C_n}\},\; Eq.5$ holds. But how this leads to cancellation of $C_i's$ in $Eq.5$ to get $\Phi_A(A_1,A_2,..,A_n)=\Phi_B(B_1B_2,..,B_n)$? I can understand this intuitively. But mathematically I found somewhat difficult to prove this, like how to use the fact that $Eq.5$ holds for any $C_i's$ and then use it to prove mathematically that we can ignore $C_i's$ from $Eq.5$?

Comment: Since the equation (5) holds for any $(C_2,.., C_N)$, we can put them all to zero and call $F(A_1,...A_N, 0,....,0)$ as $\Phi_A(A_1,...A_N)$ (and the same for the system $B$).

Comment: As $C_1=F_{AC}(A_1,A_2,....,A_N,C_2,..C_N)$, we can fix $C_2$ as $C_2^o$,... and $C_n$ as $C_n^o$ and $F_{AC}$ becomes $\Phi_A(A_1,A_2,..,A_N)=C_1$. Upto that part whole analysis is clear to me through your comment. But I have last doubt that choosing $C_1$ as LHS of $Eq.3$ and $Eq.4$ is sort of arbitrary. But thermal equilibrium guarantees that the quantity $\Phi_A(A_1,A_2,..,A_N)$ which is some $C_i$ ($C_1$ in our case) has to be temperature.

Comment: But system $C$ is determined by $N$ number of coordinates and in $Eq.3$ we can choose any of them to be LHS and thus $\Phi_A$ will be equal to that chosen coordinate which may not be temperature. How is it so? May you please explain that.

Comment: Yes, the choice is arbitrary, but the argument doesn't prove that $\Phi$ is temperature. The argument essentially proves that you can introduce such "equivalence function" $\Phi(A)$, that all states $A$ satisfying the equilibrium equation $\Phi(A)=\text{const}$ are going to be in equilibrium with each other. If you choose different $C_i$, the function $\Phi$ is going to change $\Phi_1\rightarrow \Phi_x$, but the hypersurfaces of constant values of $\Phi$ are not going to change, since your system is the same.

Comment: The only way this can happen, is if the new $\Phi_x$ is some function of the old $\Phi$, i.e. $\Phi_x(A)=f(\Phi_1(A))$.

Comment: Ok so basically the whole derivation says there is some function $\Phi$ s.t. $\Phi_A=\Phi_B$ and this is a quantity which is used as a marker to describe the equilibrium?

Comment: Yes, the "existence of temperature" usually means that for any systems $A$, $B$ and $C$ there exist such functions of state $T_A(A)$, $T_B(B)$ and $T_C(C)$, such that equality between any two such functions implies thermal equilibrium between corresponding systems. The functions are clearly not unique, since if you applied the same transformation to all of them (like, took a square of each of them), the equality of new temperatures would still imply   thermal equilibrium of systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the discussion. The discussion helps me in understanding the proof clearly.